# Maven plugin for running JWebAssembly

Tags: java, maven, gradle, webassembly, jwebassembly

I can see that JWebAssembly can be built with gradle
https://github.com/i-net-software/JWebAssembly/wiki/Build-with-Gradle
but they also provide examples for adding maven dependencies, so I would expect that there is a maven plugin as well. I can't find it anywhere. How to run JWebAssembly with maven?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is from the same github wiki(https://github.com/i-net-software/JWebAssembly/wiki/Getting-Started#add-dependency-to-api):

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>jitpack.io</id>
        <url>https://jitpack.io</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.github.i-net-software</groupId>
    <artifactId>jwebassembly-api</artifactId>
    <version>master-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

In the meantime there is a maven plugin `jwebassembly-maven` to compile your Java project with Maven to Webassmenbly.

Details can you find at [Wiki build with Maven](https://github.com/i-net-software/JWebAssembly/wiki/Build-with-Maven) and [plugin home page](https://github.com/jeff-schram/JWebAssembly-maven)